How do I set the correct permissions to let specific Google users use my Google WebApp?
I have a Google Sheet that I use as a database and from within that Sheet I wrote some AppScripts and deployed a WebApp to search said database. It runs fine when I am logged in as myself and on laptop browser. browser. I have troubles when:

Trying to let others use it. I’ve set “run as web app user” and “anyone with a google account” so far, but it doesn’t work. I get “Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again.”

I can’t even run the WebApp when logged in as myself on my iPhone’s Safari. I got the same error message as above.


So so far I can only run the web app when logged in as Myself and when on my laptop. What is the right settings here?

The error Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. shows up if there are multiple Google accounts signed in on a device. Fix issues with multiple Google Accounts states that If you're logged into multiple Google Accounts at the same time, you might have trouble accessing your add-ons and web apps. Multi-login, or being logged into multiple Google Accounts at once, isn't supported for Apps Script, add-ons, or web apps. Kindly try the steps in the documentation to see if they'll work for you.

If the same issue persists, deploy the web app as Execute the app as me and Anyone with Google account to see if it'll work.

Try using something other than Safari
